# REGEXMATCH - Multiple key words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a CRM and need to find a way to identify people who fit a variety of different words.

For example.

Column A is Dessert and options may be Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry or None.

```
=REGEXMATCH(F2, "chocolate")
```

Is what I have, but I cannot figure out how to get it to show true for two options

*I thought it would be*

```
=REGEXMATCH(F2, "chocolate"|"strawberry")
```

but that doesn't appear to be it. I am sure I am just not seeing the forest through the trees. Any guidance?

Comment: Remove the inner quotes: `=REGEXMATCH(F2, "chocolate|strawberry")`

Comment: Thank you @JvdV! I knew it was something simple I was forgetting

Comment: Welcome, just realize that `REGEXMATCH()` is both case-sensitive and slower than for example `=OR(F2="chocolate",F2="strawberry")`. I assume you have good reason to use regex though =).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(F2, "chocolate|strawberry")
```